# AWS Lambda not authorised to perform action listed in permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, permissions, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have a very simple AWS Lambda function - just listing all my CloudWatch events:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client("events")
    return client.list_rules()
```

However, when I try to run it (with an empty test event: `{}`), I am getting the following permissions exception:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListRules operation:
User: arn:aws:sts::123321123321:assumed-role/lambda+basicEvents/lambdaName 
is not authorized to perform: events:ListRules 
on resource: arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:123321123321:rule/*
```

I do have this policy attached to the lambda execution role (and I can see the actions listed in the permissions tab on the lambda):

```
{
  "document": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "BasicCloudWatchEventsManager",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "events:DescribeRule",
          "events:EnableRule",
          "events:PutRule",
          "events:ListRules",
          "events:DisableRule"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:events:*:*:rule/[*/]*"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "BasicCloudWatchEventsManager",
  "id": "SOME7LONG7ID",
  "type": "managed",
  "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123321123321:policy/BasicCloudWatchEventsManager"
}
```

I've build the policy using the visual editor they provide, just changed the `sid` manually.

Any clues what might be missing?

Comment: Could be an SCP (if you're in an environment that uses AWS Organizations) or a permission boundary kicking in. Did you try https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/ to verify?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I run this on my own account, from the AWS interface - no policy boundaries set. Didn't know of policysim, but tried it now - `denied Implicitly denied (no matching statements)`.

Comment: Gotcha. When using the policy simulator, did you provide your resource ARN?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I didn't want to provide a specific ARN, because I want to list all my rules, even the ones I plan to create in the future. But when I tried with a specific arn, or changing to `"Resource": "*"` it worked - this has lead me to the answer I posted. Thanks for your help! The policysim was a great tip.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a lot of frustration, I figured it out.
In the visual policy editor, selecting the resource as any `rule`, adding and ARN and selecting "any" for all options will create add this line in the policy:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:events:*:*:rule/[*/]*"
```

What this is meant to stand for is:

- an events resource
- in any (`*`) region
- on any account
- in any event bus, if the rule belongs to one (this is the `[*/]` part)
- with any name

However, looks like Amazon's logic is slightly broken and the optional part doesn't work and is probably taken literally. So what I had to do to fix it is to change this to:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:events:*:*:rule/*"
```

With this it works without issues.

Comment: Good catch! - saved me a lot of grief

Comment: I tried with "Resource": "*" and it worked as well.

Comment: it's no longer possible to set it to "arn:aws:events:*:*:rule/*" for it gets auto corrected to  remove the last "*"